# How to allocate memory to string with variable length?

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, malloc

I have a function that mixes 2 strings in specific way, and makes a new string, how can I allocate the memory of the new string?

I have tried adding this code but I'm not sure how to use it into a string that I don't know.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *CreateString(char *string1, char *string2) {
    int size;
    int size1 = 0;
    int size2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; *(string1 + i); i++) {
        size1++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; *(string2 + i); i++) {
        size2++;
    }

    size = (size1 * size2) + size1;

    char string[size];
    char *stringptr = string;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i = i + size2 + 1) {
        *(stringptr + i) = *(string1++);

        for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
            *(stringptr + i + j + 1) = *(string2 + j);
        }
    }
    puts(string);
}

int main() {
    char string1[] = "chocolate";
    char string2[] = "123";

    CreateString(string1, string2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Calculate the size of the new one and allocate that much (+1 for \0) with malloc.

Comment: call malloc like below: (char*)malloc(strlen(the_string) + 1). adding one for the null char ('\0)

Comment: You want to learn about `strlen`. And write `string1[i]` instead of `*(string1+i)`. Latter is not wrong but less readable.

Comment: @Adam never cast the return value of malloc.

Comment: What output do you expect? I'm pretty sure your function can be rewritten with 3-4 lines of code.

Comment: if i get kind of the same thing but with array can i use something like this(int*)malloc(sizeof(the_array) + 1)?

Comment: @jabberwocky im limited of what functions i can use

Comment: @adhamjabali please tell us what output you expect. And if you cannot use standard functions (if you are limited), you should mention this in the question. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: @Jabberwocky is it possible to use strlen on pointers?

Comment: @adhamjabali using strlen on pointers is not only possible, it's the only way.

Comment: @Jabberwocky i just need to return the new string and this string is made like this:
c123o123c123o123l123a123t123e123
but with strings that i get from user.

Comment: @adhamjabali please **[edit]** your question and put all clarifications _there_

Comment: @Jabberwocky you mean to add what this function should return?

Comment: Jabberwocky is suggesting that it is always preferable to have all of the parts of a problem available in one place (your original post).  A lot of missing parts to the problem description were only discovered as you responded to questions in the comments.   If you should ever need to ask another question, take the time to include the code (which is nicely done here), but also include what inputs should be used to obtain the desired output.  Also include what the desired output should be.  Finally, include a description of the failure you are seeing, and what you have tried to fix it.

Comment: @adhamjabali: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on they grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `strlen` routine of `string.h`:

```
size_t size=strlen(string);
size_t size2=strlen(string2);
size_t total_size=(size*size2)+size;
//now you make a malloc of a string result ugual to total_size+1 due to the fact the string end with "/0" character.
char* string_final;
 string_final=malloc(sizeof(char)*(total_size+1));
    if(string_final==NULL){
        perror("Error in malloc");
    }
    else{
     //...continue
   }
```

Comment: when i try to print using printf("%s", string3) in main it doesnt print anything...

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code, I get the string:

```
c123h123o123c123o123l123a123t123e123
```

It seems you want to add `string2` to after each character of `string2`.

So, in your case, you can call `malloc`:

```
size = (size1 * size2) + size1;
char *string = malloc(size + 1); // +1 for null character
if(!string) {
   printf("cannot malloc for string\n");
   return NULL;
}
```

You function should return `string` at the end. Do not forget to free the return value of this function when you do not want to use `string` to avoid memory leak.

This code below:

```
    for(int i=0;*(string1+i);i++){
        size1++;
    }

    for(int i=0;*(string2+i);i++){
        size2++;
    }
```

Can be replaced by `strlen` function:

```
size1 = strlen(string1);
size2 = strlen(string2);
```

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char) * size + 1)` is inconsistent: either use `malloc(size + 1)` or `malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1))`. all 3 expressions evaluate to the same value but yours mixes apples and oranges.

Comment: @chqrlie You are right because `(sizeof(char)` is always equal to `1`. I will edit the code.

Comment: so i add this if(!string)... and use else for the rest of my function?
and that makes it return Null or the string if allowed?

Comment: @adhamjabali of course, you can do `if ... else`. Or you can just use `if(string) {/*your rest of code*/}` It 's just a way you handle the error. If your code gets the error, you do not have to do any thing with your rest of code

Answer (score 1):

Given your description,   [from comments,given: "chocolate" "123" as user inputs]
*"...string is made like this: c123o123c123o123l123a123t123e123 but with strings that i get from user."*
`CreateString` could be as simple as this:

```
char * CreateString(const char* string1,const char* string2)
{
    int len1 = strlen(string1);
    int len2 = strlen(string2);
    char *ptr = string1;

    char tempBuf[len1 + len1*len2 +1];// intermediate content buffer

    char *newString = calloc(len1 + len1*len2 +1, 1);
    if(newString)//test return of malloc
    {
        while(*ptr != NULL)//while each character is not NULL, stay in loop
        {//use combination of sprintf and strcat to interleave
         //components of new string
            sprintf(tempBuf, "%s%c", newString, *ptr);
            strcat(tempBuf, string2);
            sprintf(newString, "%s", tempBuf);
            ptr++;//increment pointer to next char in string1
        }                  
    }
    return newString;  //calling function should always check for null before using
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])//Use this signature rather than 
{                               //int main(void) to allow user input
    if(argc != 3) //simple verification that command line contains 2 arguments
    {
        printf("%s\n", "Usage: prog.exe <string1> <string2>");
        return 0;
    }
    char *newString = CreateString(argv[1],argv[2]);
    if(newString)
    {   
        printf( "Resulting string is: %s\n", newString);
        free(newString); //free when finished
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

With user inputs of `"chocolate"` and `"123"`, program returns:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can allocate memory for the string with

```
char *stringptr = malloc(size + 1);
```

Note that you code can be simplified with string functions from `<string.h>`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *CreateString(const char *string1, const char *string2) {
    size_t size1 = strlen(string1);
    size_t size2 = strlen(string2);
    size_t size = size1 * (size2 + 1);
    char *stringptr = malloc(size + 1);

    if (stringptr) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i = i + size2 + 1) {
            stringptr[i] = *string1++;
            strcpy(stringptr + i + 1, string2);
        }
    }
    return stringptr;
}

int main() {
    char string1[] = "chocolate";
    char string2[] = "123";
    char *string3 = CreateString(string1, string2);
    if (string3) {
        printf("%s\n", string3);
        free(string3);
    } else {
        printf("cannot allocate memory\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i cant add const to my function but it really helped me to know things, the i did the same as you i returned the stringptr but when i print it it only prints a space do you have any idea why"?

Comment: @adhamjabali: why can't you add the `const` in the prototype of `CreateString`? the arguments should be declared as `const char *` to indicate that this function does not modify these argument strings. I compiled the above code on my system and get the expected output: `c123h123o123c123o123l123a123t123e123`. How did you copy the code? What system do you use?

Comment: ye it was a problem with me copying the code i fixed it thank you very much.